# Laravel - empty result by trying to show a specific thread

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My database is filled with data and showing all data works. But if I try to show a specific thread only, I get an empty result and I can't figure out why.

**web.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/threads', 'ThreadsController@index');
Route::get('/threads/{threads}', 'ThreadsController@show');
```

ThreadsController@index works, but ThreadsController@show doesn't work.

**ThreadsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Thread;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ThreadsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $threads = Thread::latest()->get();
        return view('threads.index', compact('threads'));
        //return $threads;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Thread  $thread
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Thread $thread)
    {
        //return view('threads.show', compact('thread'));
        return $thread;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Thread  $thread
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Thread $thread)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Thread  $thread
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Thread $thread)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Thread  $thread
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Thread $thread)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is an example from laracast tutorial: [link](https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/2?autoplay=true)

Why this example doesn't work? I can't find any typo in my code.
My version:

```
php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.4.32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your show route to the following:

```
Route::get('/threads/{thread}', 'ThreadsController@show');
```

You are loading a `Thread` object, and not a `Threads` object.

Comment: According to this tutorial `Route::get('/threads/{id}', 'ThreadsController@show');` should make the same, but I get an empty result again by using {id} . Can you explaine me why {id} doesn't work, please?

Comment: The part name should be the same as the type hinted variable in the function. [As explained in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#implicit-binding).